# Why did Stack Overflow allow a one-line answer without explanation?

Tags: discussion

Why did Stack Overflow allow a one-line **answer** without explanation?

Like *[Printing leading 0's in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c)*

Comment: While those answers are usually not good, they are allowed. And...it was 9 years ago when the site was a baby

Comment: Because it allows one-line questions.

Comment: Because we only delete answer posts when they're not actually answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer

Comment: Examples are the mashed potatoes, explanations are the gravy

Comment: Meh code only answers do bug me but this one is so old I really wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Posters ask for one-line answers.  Posters often ask for one-word answers: 'Is it possible.........'., though they do tend to get annoyed when answerers are 'mean and unhelpful' and refuse to read between the lines.

Comment: At least it didn't say "Try this" before it.

Comment: Anyone with sufficient rep could add an explanation.

Comment: When I am reviewing this autodetection one line answers shell I write a comment that the person shell explain the code or is this unneccessary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It answers the question quite concisely.  Granted, it's not explained, and even (as some comments and other answer suggest) not best practice.  Feel free to downvote it if you think it's not helpful or otherwise bad.  But it's allowed because it is ultimately an answer.